# Help with LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I usually do just fine, but for some reason I cannot figure out why this particular query is defeating me.

For simplicity here is the database(Brand and PageTitle):

[image]

PageTitle is just a table to hold SEO data(there is only one row per `Brand`)

I want to : Select one row from `PageTitle` where brands = p (variable that holds the query string value)

This is an example of what I'm trying to do (If there are no records for the brand in `PageTitle` I don't want to throw an error).

```
var pages = da.PageTitles.Where(x => x.Brands.Single(z => z.BrandID == p)).SingleOrDefault();
                if (pages.Any())
                {
                    txtSeoTitle.Text = pages.Title;
                    txtSeoMetaKeywords.Text = pages.Keywords;
                    txtSeoMetaDesc.Text = pages.Description;
                }
```

Comment: well the `SingleOrDefault` could return `null` and then calling the `Any` extension would throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless i'm missing something obvious, can't you just do this:

```
var page = db.PageTitles
              .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Brands.Any(y => y.BrandId == p));
```

`SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if more than one row is returned, so i think you need `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: I think that may be the query i'm looking for but I need to wrap the text boxes in an if statement and `if(pages){...` doesn't work.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if no items match the predicate. So just do `if (page) != null { txtSeoTitle.Text = page.Title; }` etc etc